# unicode char for gvaṁ and how it is pronounced correctly

Tags: scripture, vedas, upanishads, shloka, vedic-chanting

Wanted to know how the word

> gvaṁ

ग्वं

pronounced correctly and written represented in unicode, For example in this sloka

```
स विश्वकृद्विश्वविदात्मयोनिर्ज्ञः कालकारो गुणी सर्वविद्‌ यः।
प्रधानक्षेत्रज्ञपतिर्गुणेशः ससारमोक्षस्थितिबन्धहेतुः॥
```

from https://upanishads.org.in/upanishads/9/6/16
the word `ससार` contains a char which on copying becomes ``
Although the above link also contains a recitation of sloka but not sure if its correct?

Comment: ज्ञ, and the unicode is a compound byte `U+091CU+094DU+091E`

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha
maybe I don't understand well. my understanding was its not *ज्ञ*
otherwise it would have printed/pronounced correctly like *क्षेत्रज्ञ*
but in the word *ससार* it is not.

To me it sounds more like `anga` the char * ँ* but not sure.

Comment: सः विश्वकृत् विश्ववित् आत्मयोनिः। ज्ञः कालकाः गुणी सर्वविद्यः प्रधानक्षेत्रज्ञपतिः गुणेशः सम्सारमोक्षस्थितिबन्धहेतुः भवति ॥